# How to count rows of a query group by?

Tags: sql

I want to write a query to return rows of a query.

I am trying like this:

```
 // This query returns 2 rows in a result and I want to count that 2 output rows 
 // but not able to count output rows

SELECT a.*, b.* FROM TABLE_1 AS A INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON (a.id = b.id) GROUP BY b.name;
```

Output

```
    id      name       occupation
     5       John       Plumber
    19      Mark       Electrician
```

I am trying to count rows like below "trows":

```
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.name) AS trows, a.*, b.* FROM TABLE_1 AS A INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON (a.id = b.id) GROUP BY b.name;
```

Output

```
 trows   id      name       occupation
  7      5       John       Plumber
  4      19      Mark       Electrician
```

**"COUNT(DISTINCT a.name) AS trows"** it is not working for me to count the query rows.

The query return two rows only but I am not able to count that two rows.

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: `row_number()`... but older MySql doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.name) AS trows
FROM TABLE_1 A INNER JOIN
     TABLE_2 B
     ON a.id = b.id;
```

The only way this could miscount the rows is if `a.name` is ever `NULL`.  If you need to take that into account, you can adjust:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.name) + MAX(a.name IS NULL) AS trows
FROM TABLE_1 A INNER JOIN
     TABLE_2 B
     ON a.id = b.id;
```

Note that your `GROUP BY` query is malformed and should be rejected as a syntax error:  the `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY`.  Even the more recent versions of MySQL would generate an error.